# React-Native Disabling swipe gesture to open drawer in a nested StackNavigator specific screen

Tags: android, react-native

Consider the following screens where I have:

```
Main Drawer Navigator
|---Stack 1
    |--- Menu 1
    |--- Menu 2
|---Stack 2
    |--- Menu 3
    |--- Menu 4
```

I have a Drawer Navigator as my main navigator while having two nested stack navigators containing their own respective screens.

How do I disable the swipe gesture to open the drawer menu in the child menus (Menu 1 - 4) ?

I know I can disable the swipe gesture for menus (Stack 1 and 2) by doing `drawerLockMode` but how do I do the same for the stack childs?